# Install button greyed out in internet recovery mode

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, install

Using Internet recovery, I erased my MacBook pro and tried to Reinstall OSX. I was given the choice to Reinstall Mavericks. I selected the Macintosh HD. Here, the INSTALL button is greyed out! Here I am stuck to proceed ahead. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Mavericks? That’s eight years old. What model MacBook Pro? If it can run a newer OS you can obtain it here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683

Comment: It was Mavericks at the time of purchasing. Since then it was being upgraded and had BigSur finally with MacBook Pro 15" (Late 2013).

Comment: Option+Command+R or Shift+Option+Command+R should offer the latest or at least something newer than Mavericks.